# Resolution Change (Besiege)

Tags: besiege

So I recently bought besiege but I noticed the resolution if off and I can't read the text, I don't see a setting for this, does anyone know how to change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Besiege_Data folder there is a Config.txt file where you can change Resolution Width and Height to anything.

The Besiege_Data folder can be found in the main game folder, you can find this by right clicking the game in your library on steam, clicking properties, Click the local files tab and select browse to local files.

Alternatively if you've installed everything to default locations it will be here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common`

Comment: When in that folder all I see is the Besiege app no other folders

Comment: @bucky yes go into the beseige folder, and in there is the data one

Comment: you can also just run a search for Config.txt if you're having trouble finding it